# Create specific CPU load % for a specific HTTP request rate using PHP?

Tags: php, http, load, cpu, utilization

How to create an exact amount of artificial CPU load using *PHP*? I am looking for *PHP* code that generates 1% CPU utilization for 1 HTTP request per second. That means I can get 50% CPU utilization using 50 HTTP requests per second; and 80% CPU utilization using a rate of 80 HTTP requests per second, and so on.

Comment: i don't believe that's going to be possible, php certainly is not the language for such a task

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible doing it using *PHP*. You should look into virtualization systems. For example, [**Cloudmin**](http://webmin.com/cloudmin.html):

- Using Cloudmin you can create, destroy, resize, startup, shutdown and restrict multiple instances using different virtualization technologies from a single interface. It also has a full command line API that can be used to manage virtual systems from a shell script or via HTTP requests.
- Cloudmin supports additional logins called system owners, who can be given limited access to a subset of virtual systems, and can be restricted in the actions that they perform. Owners can have **limits set on their disk, RAM and CPU usage** that apply across all their virtual systems, either defined on a per-owner limit or from a plan.